# Playing audio files on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-audio

I've made a simple app, where I have a list of songs.  The user taps a list entry and the song begins playing.

I've lifted the SoundEffect class from Apple's sample projects (e.g. Metronome, BubbleLevel).  It seems to work fine with the following code:

```
// declare in the .h file
SoundEffect *audio;

// setup - when controller loads
audio = [SoundEffect alloc];

// play when user taps entry
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];   
[audio initWithContentsOfFile:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"entry1" ofType:@"mp3"]];
[audio play];
```

However, if the 'audio' object is already playing, I'd like to stop it before it starts playing the sound again.  SoundEffect class does not have a stop method or I am simply missing something.

How do i stop the audio before playing it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don’t you simply use [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this class.  One gotcha about it is that if you [play] the file, then [stop] the audio, and then [play] again, it'll start playing where it left off.  The trick is to set .currentTime to 0 when you stop.

Answer (score 1):

The `SoundEffect` class is a wrapper around the C-based System Sounds API (see the [.m file](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/BubbleLevel/listing11.html) from the Bubble Level project), which is a simple "fire and forget" style API that doesn't provide a "stop" function.  More info in the [System Sounds Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).

I also agree with (and have voted up) zoul's suggestion to use `AVAudioPlayer`.  System Sounds are wholly inappropriate for long, encoded audio files like songs in MP3 files.